# Merge 2 xml files with xslt and conditionality

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to merge two xml files with updates based on conditionality. In the first file you will notice that there are 3 sequences of SECTION_SUMMARY. The 3rd Sequence has a LockAuthority Attri bute of "1".

```
    File1.xml
     <DOCUMENT>
      <LOANS>
       <LOAN SequenceNumber="1" xlink:label="LOAN1" LoanRoleType="SubjectLoan">
    <DOCUMENT_SETS>
     <DOCUMENT_SET>
      <GFE>
       <SECTION_SUMMARIES>
        <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="1">
         <Amount>1975.00</Amount>
         <Type>A</Type>
        </SECTION_SUMMARY>
        <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="2">    
         <Amount>9751.44</Amount>   
         <Type>B</Type>                    
        </SECTION_SUMMARY>
        <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="3" LockAuthority="1">
         <Amount>3750.00</Amount>
         <Type>A</Type>
        </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       </SECTION_SUMMARIES>
      </GFE>
     </DOCUMENT_SET>
    </DOCUMENT_SETS>
    <ESCROW>
     <ESCROW_DETAIL>
      <InsuranceIndicator>true</InsuranceIndicator>
      <AllPropertyTaxesIndicator>true</AllPropertyTaxesIndicator>
      <OtherDescription>HOA</OtherDescription>
     </ESCROW_DETAIL>
    </ESCROW>
       </LOAN>
      </LOANS>
     </DOCUMENT>
```

In the second file there are sequences 3 through 5. Sequence 3 which appears in both files has a LockAuthority attribute with a value of "2". If the value is greater than or equal to value in File 1 then value comes from File2 else value from File1. I also want any datapoints with out LockAuthority that were not in File1 merged. If there is no LockAuthority the data from File2 will prevail.

```
File2.xml
   <DOCUMENT>
    <LOANS>
     <LOAN SequenceNumber="1" xlink:label="LOAN1" LoanRoleType="SubjectLoan">
       <DOCUMENT_SETS>
    <DOCUMENT_SET>
     <GFE>
      <SECTION_SUMMARIES>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="3" LockAuthority="2">
        <Amount>200.00</Amount>
        <Type>Header</Type>
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="4"> 
        <Amount>-3000.00</Amount>   
        <Type>Two</Type>                       
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="5">
        <Amount>5392.25</Amount>
        <Type>Three</Type>
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
      </SECTION_SUMMARIES>
     </GFE>
    </DOCUMENT_SET>
       </DOCUMENT_SETS>
     </LOAN>
    </LOANS>
   </DOCUMENT>
```

The resulting file should look like this.

```
   <DOCUMENT>
    <LOANS>
     <LOAN SequenceNumber="1" xlink:label="LOAN1" LoanRoleType="SubjectLoan">
       <DOCUMENT_SETS>
    <DOCUMENT_SET>
     <GFE>
      <SECTION_SUMMARIES>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="1">
        <Amount>1975.00</Amount>
        <Type>A</Type>
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="2"> 
        <Amount>9751.44</Amount>    
        <Type>B</Type>                     
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="3" LockAuthority="2">
        <Amount>200.00</Amount>
        <Type>Header</Type>
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="4"> 
        <Amount>-3000.00</Amount>   
        <Type>Two</Type>                       
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
       <SECTION_SUMMARY SequenceNumber="5">
        <Amount>5392.25</Amount>
        <Type>Three</Type>
       </SECTION_SUMMARY>
      </SECTION_SUMMARIES>
     </GFE>
    </DOCUMENT_SET>
       </DOCUMENT_SETS>
       <ESCROW>
    <ESCROW_DETAIL>
     <InsuranceIndicator>true</InsuranceIndicator>
     <AllPropertyTaxesIndicator>true</AllPropertyTaxesIndicator>
     <OtherDescription>HOA</OtherDescription>
    </ESCROW_DETAIL>
       </ESCROW>
     </LOAN>
    </LOANS>
   </DOCUMENT>
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here are straightforward solution  (Could be improved by using xsl:key).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="f2" select="document('ic4_2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SECTION_SUMMARY_F1" select="//SECTION_SUMMARY"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SECTION_SUMMARY" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SECTION_SUMMARY[@LockAuthority]">
        <xsl:variable name="SECTION_SUMMARY_F2" select="$f2//SECTION_SUMMARY[@SequenceNumber = current()/@SequenceNumber]" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$SECTION_SUMMARY_F2/@LockAuthority > @LockAuthority">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$SECTION_SUMMARY_F2" mode="copy"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SECTION_SUMMARIES">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- from file 1-->
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <!-- from file 2-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$f2//SECTION_SUMMARY[not(@SequenceNumber = $SECTION_SUMMARY_F1/@SequenceNumber)]" >
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I changed the file name on line 5 to my file name and ran this. I got only the data that was in File1. Did I miss something?

Comment: Should work. (I tested it with xsltproc) Are the XML-files and the xslt in the same directory? Dit you do the test with the xml files you have posted? Perhaps there are namespaces involved in your test (because of xlink:label)?

Comment: Files are all in the same directory. Copied your answer to new file and saved to same directory. Assigned new xslt to File1 and executed XSL Transformation. I am using XMLSpy. Tried removing labels also. I am using the same files that I posted. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Than this seems to be an XMLSpy issue. This works actually with different browser FireFox, Chrome, IE.

Comment: I am trying to get access to another tool. Probably Stylus Studio 2007. Hope that will work. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, got the Stylus Studio and that didn't work either. Tell me more about this tool that you are using.

Comment: Sounds strange. Stylus Studio and XMLSpy a development tools and should work anyway. I using command line tools like xsltproc (windows and linux), msxsl.exe (windows) and some time ago Saxon XSLT.